# How can I change the read only variables on xampp?

Tags: mysql

I am installing moodle. So, I have to change innodb_file_format variable to barracuda. But it's read only variable.

---

Comment: What Operating System are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You have to change it in my.cnf and restart mysqld.

Answer (score 0):

In window OS,
XAMPP server-

```
         1.open XAMPP control panel.

         2.MYSQL Config File(my.ini) open the file.

         3.include variable - innodb_file_format=Your input value.

         4.after restart your xampp.
```